# Java Access Denied

Tags: java, windows-7, javac

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin>javac VendingMachine.java
VendingMachine.java:27: error while writing VendingMachine: VendingMachine.class
 (Access is denied)
public class VendingMachine
       ^
1 error
```

Here is the code from my editior from line 27 to 39:

```
public class VendingMachine /*This is line 27*/
{
   private int itemPrice;

   private int currentBalance;

   private int totalCollected;

   public VendingMachine(int itemCost)
   {
       itemPrice = itemCost;

   } /*line 39*/
```

I am thinking my problem might be related to Win7 Prof:
(Access is denied)

How do I resolve this or what do I need to be doing or reading to get this to work?

Thank you for not flaming.

I just changed the folder options such that I am the given full (Access...), now I just have to figure out why I am not getting any output, when running javac VendingMachine.java
I guess a new question  is in order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your working directory is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin`. You are not allowed to write files here. Copy your java files to a different directory and try to compile them there.

**edit:**

You should include `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin` to your `PATH` environment variable. And set `JAVA_PATH` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17`.

```
set JAVA_PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17"
set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin"
```

After that, you can call `javac` from where ever you like.

Comment: I can only run javac from \bin directory, javac outside of bin directory will not be recognized.

Comment: Add the JDK bin directory to your path or use the fully qualified path, such as: `PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin";%PATH%`

Comment: That's so wicked cool, dude you are a code ninja, that rocks:
set JAVA_PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17"
set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin"

Answer (score 4):

You don't have write access in C:\Program Files (x86). Put your sources elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error, just Run Cmd prompt as Administration mode.Hope it will solve your Problem!

Comment: Should be a comment