# Java Compile Error (HelloWorldApp); It shows "Error while writing" and "Access Denied"

Tags: java, cmd

I use Windows 7 and recently installed JDK (jdk1.8.0_05). (I've also installed JRE)
As I'm new to Java, I complied the Hello World Java code given on [Official Java Website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html):

```
class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
    }
}
```

I saved the file as `C:\HelloWorldApp.java`

And then in command prompt, I typed

```
javac HelloWorldApp.java
```

I got the following message:

```
C:/HelloWorldApp.java:5: error: error while starting HelloWorldApp: C:\HelloWorldApp.class (Access is denied)

class HelloWorldApp{
^
1 error
```

PS: I even tried making the class public. Also, I've specified PATH variable as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin`

What may be the solution?

Comment: Maybe not compiling in `C:\ ` root?

Comment: _error while starting HelloWorldApp: C:\HelloWorldApp.class (Access is denied)_ It means that your user is not able to write files on that directory. Compile it in another directory, maybe in `C:\Users\Your User\Documents`

Comment: I believe you have the same problem as described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939656/java-access-denied

Comment: You mean I should try it in C:\Program Files\Java or D:\? - I've done that, but that doesn't help.

Comment: No, I've read  stackoverflow.com/questions/1939656/java-access-denied and that didn't help it.

Comment: Your issue _is_ the same. And you _haven't_ read the answers to that question. This has nothing to do with `PATH`. This is due to your cwd being wrong.

Comment: Dude, I tried keeping that file in My documents folder and D drive, but it shows the same error. PS: In D drive, Access is _not_ denied, as I save all my MS-Word or C/C++ or Python files directly over there. @BoristheSpider

Answer (score -2):

Add `public` keyword before the `class` keyword. That is, change:

```
class HelloWorldApp {
```

to

```
public class HelloWorldApp {
```

The class that contains main method must be declared as public.

Comment: It does not have to be public

Comment: I tried adding public class, that doesn't help.

Comment: This is a file permission issue, not a class visibility error.